# Update the number of likes in Post using swift (Firebase database)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
var postRef:DatabaseReference {
return Database.database().reference().child("posts")
}

@IBAction func LikePostTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

postRef.observeSingleEvent(of:.value, with: { [self] (snapshot) in

    if snapshot.children.allObjects is [DataSnapshot] {
        
        count =  count + 1
        LikeCount.text = "\(count)"
        LikeCount.textColor = UIColor.red
        postRef.updateChildValues(["likes":count])
}
})


}
```

I am trying to update the number of likes for each post in my database. However when i click the like button its saves the number of likes in a new child node in firebase and not in the likes child node on the particular post. Here is a picture that shows what i mean.

PICTURE LINK: https://i.stack.imgur.com/64wLn.png

Comment: What's this?  Database.database().reference().child("posts")

Comment: How could Firebase tell which record you are referring to?

Comment: Change 'postRef.updateChildValues(["likes":count])' for 'snapshot.child("likes").setValue(count)'

Comment: when i change the code to snapshot.child("likes").setValue(count) , i get this error....Value of type 'DataSnapshot' has no member 'child'

Comment: child(posts) is the first node in the database, if you have a look at the picture in the link you can see it there. I still haven’t  figured out how to tell firebase which post i am referring to when i hit the like button

Comment: Please don't include links in the question; include your Firebase structure as text so it's searchable and we can copy/paste it in an answer if needed. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure in the question.

Comment: Where does `count` come from?

Comment: It is variable that I declared to equal 0 initially.

Comment: Right. But how do you know what likes is? e.g. to increment a counter, you need to read the existing value, increment it and write the new value back out. The code shown in the question doesn't do that. It's also writing data directly to the *posts* node. e.g. *posts/likes* will be overwritten each time the code is run. I would think you would want to update */posts/some post id/likes* instead

Answer (score 1):

Use particular postId (posts child) to get to exact location where likes are kept as I used roomId
use updateChildValues update previous like status:

```
func updateStatus (roomId: String, totalLikes: String) {
    self.dbReference.child("posts").child(roomId).updateChildValues(["likes": totalLikes])
}
```